# Why does gtime command return CPU usage > 100% for java program with no multithreading?

Tags: java, unix, time

I tried using the gtime command (I believe that this is the Mac OSx equivalent to the Unix time command) to get the execution time for a java program. But the results seem confusing as:

1. The CPU usage shows >100% even though the program does not spawn any threads.
2. The real-time is way less than the user-time even though there is no multithreading in my code.

Here is what I get:

> > gtime java Main
>
> 7.36user 0.29system 0:02.11elapsed 362%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 306264maxresident)k 0inputs+0outputs (273major+114934minor)pagefaults 0swaps

As you can see, CPU usage is 362% and user time(7.36s) >> real-time(2.11s). Can anyone explain why this is the case? I'm using a Macbook Pro that has an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz (4 cores) processor.

On a side note, running a 'hello world' program in Java also returns a CPU usage >100%.

> > gtime java HelloWorld
>
> Hello World!
> 0.14user 0.04system 0:00.14elapsed 124%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 33668maxresident)k 0inputs+0outputs (0major+10288minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: The MacOS command to time the execution of another executable is `time` - I'm not sure where you `gtime` command comes from. Try the same with `time`

Comment: Yes you're right. But the time command in Mac has different flags in comparison to the Unix time command. This is gnu-time installed using brew...which has the exact same command structure as the Unix time command. Of course, I used MacOS time command as well and it gives me the same result for real time vs user time, but this command doesn't return CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JVM starts multiple background threads even when you run a simple `main()` program. These threads are performing JIT compilation, RMI handling, object finalization or other system tasks. You can see these threads by either manually debugging or taking a thread dump. Second, most garbage collector implementations used today are either parallel or multi-threaded (or both) and will attempt to use all available CPU cores to shorten the GC pause.

All of the above will lead to more than one CPU core being used by the JVM. Most tools will report this as over 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. Just a follow-up, is this behaviour expected with other programming languages like Python and C++? Because I'd assume that they'd use similar optimisations...however when I run python or C++ programs, I always get user-time < real-time and CPU usage <= 100%.

Comment: There is no rule however, it's entirely up to language. You can try [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and compile Java to native binary and see what happens.